# Ограничение на вызов скрипта php

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который может иногда вызываться по несколько раз в секунду. В этом скрипте стоит curl запрос на сторонний сайт. Так вот если этот скрипт выполняется чаще чем 1 раз в секунду, сторонний сайт банит айпи скрипта на некоторое время.
Как сделать, чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся не чаще чем 1 раз в секунду?
А точнее, чтобы curl выполнялся не часто? Может как то использовать sleep? В общем все мои идеи зашли в тупик, нужна помощь.

Comment: а почему самому нельзя смотреть удалённый ресурс раз в 10 секунд, например, а пользователям отдавать то, что сами получили?

Comment: нельзя, много разных запросов. Поясню, это просмотр инвентаря в steam.

Comment: Кстати, если вы дадите больше информации об остальном ПО, то больше шансов получить полезный вам ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вызов скрипта есть процедурой независимой. Чтобы хранить информацию о вызовах можете вести журнал запусков а) записывая в БД, б) сохраняя в файл

Скрипт запускается - проверяет БД или файл и принимает решение

--Добавил--

`sleep` не поможет. Пока один запуск спит, другой волен запуститься

Comment: есть косяк в такой схеме. Если идут одновременно например 3 запроса, то одновременно пойдут запросы mysql, и всем 3-им mysql даст добро. Вот в этом и проблема

Comment: Проверяли? То есть сервер успевает обработать 3 запроса, запустить 3 скрипта (с выгрузкой в память, передачей серверных данных в виде массивов и тп), а файловая система/СУБД не успевает? По-Станиславскому - не верю

Comment: Поверьте. У меня был подобный скрипт, он добавлял в БД пункт если указанного наименования в нем нету. Так вот у меня в базе оказалось куча дублей, как раз потому что первый SELECT пропускал остальные одновременные запросы

Comment: а) используйте файл. Ведь скрипт обрабатывается как файл, не быстрее файловых процессов. б) поставьте sleep в начале скрипта на 10 мс. Человек не заметит, БД успеет сделать свои дела

Comment: "Так вот у меня в базе оказалось куча дублей, как раз потому что первый SELECT пропускал остальные одновременные запросы" - там в чём проблема явно установить WRITE LOCK при первом SELECT?

Comment: не знал что такое WRITE LOCK. Сейчас читаю документацию, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы, мне посоветовали использовать mysql и блокировку WRITE LOCK
Я никогда не работал с блокировками, и мне сейчас немного сложно понять принцип их работы.
Собственно могли бы кому не сложно написать простой пример блокировок в моей ситуации?

Comment: типа в начале скрипта делаю запрос LOCK TABLES `table` WRITE; потом SELECT `lasttime`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS `unixtime` FROM `table`; если разница lasttime и unixtime больше допустим 10-ти, то скрипт выдает ошибку и на всякий случай запрос в таблицу UNLOCK TABLES; Ну а если разница не больше, то дает curl а потом UPDATE `table` SET `lasttime`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); Скажите если я все правильно понял.