# Блокировка таблиц LOCK WRITE в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно чтобы скрипт на PHP выполнялся 1 раз в 10 секунд. Мне посоветовали использовать `LOCK TABLES`. С этой штукой я совсем не знаком, и боюсь накосячить. В общем если я правильно понимаю, то:
в начале скрипта делаю запрос `LOCK TABLES table WRITE`;
потом `SELECT lasttime, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS unixtime FROM table;`
если разница `lasttime` и `unixtime` больше 10-ти, то скрипт выдает ошибку
на всякий случай делаем запрос в таблицу `UNLOCK TABLES;`

Ну а если разница не больше 1-ти, то выполняю скрипт после чего делаю
`UPDATE table SET lasttime=UNIX_TIMESTAMP();` 
и в конце `UNLOCK TABLES;`

Если я так сделаю, то одновременные коннекты к скрипту не дадут сбой? Правильно я понимаю принцип работы блокировок?

Comment: `Мне посоветовали использовать LOCK TABLES.` Больше никогда не слушайте этого "советчика". А выполнение PHP-скрипта с заданной периодичностью обеспечивайте средствами планировщика - ОС или (если там есть) PHP.

Comment: этот скрипт юзают люди, бывает что одновременно юзают его, а мне так делать нельзя. Вот и нужно придумать ограничение

Comment: Заведите служебную таблицу, в которую записывайте, кто и во сколько запустил скрипт. На старте скрипта делаем `SELECT ... WHERE dt < NOW()( - INTERVAL 10 SECOND FOR UPDATE`. Если запись вернулась - апдейтим её и начинаем основные операции, иначе завершаем работу.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за подсказку, не знал про FOR UPDATE. Посоветовал WRITE LOCK я и не знал про FOR UPDATE. Это реально полезный комментарий, который надо превратить в ответ. А вот предыстория: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642883/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-php

Comment: @Akina, ну, с учётом того, что у товарища InnoDB